# Selecting documents with a specific field is set to NULL in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Someone please help me to add `expires_at IS NULL` to ES query below. I looked into [Dealing with Null Values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_dealing_with_null_values.html#_exists_missing_on_objects) section for `missing` filter but the way I used it (shown at the bottom) causes not expired documents not appearing in result so obviously I'm doing something wrong here.

*Note:* I don't want to use `or query` because it is [deprecated in 2.0.0-beta1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/query-dsl-or-query.html).

**QUERY**

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "order_id": "123"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "is_active": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "expires_at": {
                  "gt": "2016-07-01T00:00:00+0000"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I'm aiming at:

```
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE
order_id = '123' AND
is_active = '1' AND
(expires_at > '2016-07-01T00:00:00+0000' OR expires_at IS NULL)
```

This is what I did, but un-expired documents won't show up in this case so this is wrong.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "missing": {
          "field": "expires_at"
        }
      },
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            ......
            ......
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My ES version:

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Fan Boy",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.3.4",
    "build_hash" : "a70f3ccb52200f8f2c87e9c370c6597448eb3e45",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-09-30T09:07:17Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.9"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "order_id": "123"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "is_active": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "expires_at": {
                        "gt": "20160101000000"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "filtered": {
                      "filter": {
                        "missing": {
                          "field": "expires_at"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Getting error: `{"code":500,"message":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[3JYUoUpWRya90oiKlk2RGQ][my_index_dev][0]: SearchParseException[[my_index_dev][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source .... actual query appear here .... nested: QueryParsingException[[my_index_dev] No query registered for [missing]];`

Comment: Updated the query. Haven't thought you are using such an old version. Btw, you should upgrade.

Comment: That's the one! Thank you very much. Upgrade will take place one day :)